# lag shift a long table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
ticker,  t,             shout_t     shout_tminus
A        2010-01-01      22
A        2010-01-02      23
A        2010-01-03      24
B        2010-01-01      44
B        2010-01-02      55
B        2010-01-03      66
C        2010-01-01      100
C        2010-01-02      22
C        2010-01-03      33
```

I want to lag shift this dataframe by 1 day and compute the shout_minus value.  ideally, i would have done df.shift(1), but this will be a mistake.  ideally i would like:

```
A      2010-01-01      22     NA
A      2010-01-02      23     22
A      2010-01-03      24     23
```

for the last value of shout_tminus.  Likewise for B and C.   I did the following:

```
ids = ['A','B','C']
df['shoutminus'] = None
for key in ids:
    temp = df[df.ticker == key].copy()
    temp['shout_tminus'] = temp['shout_t'].shift(1)
    df.update(temp)
```

Problem is if my dataframe is too large, I have a 10million row dataframe, just doing this operation for 1000 tickers takes forever.  Is there a faster way to shift a series correctly for a long table df? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to add a `groupby('ticker')`:

```
df['shout_tminus'] = (
   df.sort_values(['ticker', 't'])
   .groupby('ticker')
   ['shout_t']
   .shift()
)
```

Result:

```
ticker           t  shout_t  shout_tminus
     A  2010-01-01       22           NaN
     A  2010-01-02       23          22.0
     A  2010-01-03       24          23.0
     B  2010-01-01       44           NaN
     B  2010-01-02       55          44.0
     B  2010-01-03       66          55.0
     C  2010-01-01      100           NaN
     C  2010-01-02       22         100.0
     C  2010-01-03       33          22.0
```

Comment: @ScottBoston you are right, it's just my preference for an explicit sort

Answer (score 1):

IICU:
Are you looking for? What will happen though to the last row?

```
df['shout_tminus']=df.shift().shout_t
df
```

[image]

Comment: The possible problem with this is that the last T for Ticker A will become the first shout_t for Ticker B.  This is not likely what you want.

Comment: @Scott Boston, you're right. Thats why I wondered 'What will happen though to the last row?'